# Change file name upload image in Django

Tags: javascript, python, django

Im having a trouble on how can I rename my image file to prevent duplication of filename. Currently I have a list of photos which can upload the filename to the database and it will automatically create folder and save those selected photos to my `media` folder. All I want is every image filename must be unique. It would be great if anybody could figure out where I am doing something wrong. thank you so much in advance

*views.py*

```
@login_required(login_url='log_permission')
def scanned_docs_add(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        gallery = folder_info.objects.create(
        title = request.POST.get('title'),
        date_upload = datetime.date.today()
    )
    for file in request.FILES.getlist('photos[]'): #imagefile--------
        oas = gallery_photos.objects.create(
            gallery_info_id = gallery.id,
            photos = file,
        )
return JsonResponse({'data': 'success'})
```

*models.py*

```
class folder_info(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True, null=True)
    date_upload = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = "folder_info"

class gallery_photos(models.Model):
    gallery_info_id = models.IntegerField()
    photos = models.FileField(upload_to='Photos/', unique=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'gallery_photos'
```

*html*

```
  <form id="uploadevent" >
  {% csrf_token %}
   <input type="file" multiple data-bind="fileInput: multiFileData, customFileInput: {                                                                 
      }" accept="image/*" name="photos[]" required="">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Save changes</button>
  </form>
```

*Script*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#uploadevent').on('submit', function(e){
  $.ajax({
      data        : new FormData(this),
      url         : "{% url 'scanned_docs_add' %}",
      type        : 'POST',
      cache       : false,
      contentType : false,
      processData : false
  })
  .done(function(data){
      var info = data.data;
      if(info){
          $('#uploadevent').modal('toggle');
          toastrOptions();
          toastr.success("Successfully Saved!",{
              timeOut: 1000,
              fadeOut: 1000,
              onHidden: function(){
                  window.location.reload();
              }
          });
          $('#uploadevent').trigger('reset');    
      }
  });

  e.preventDefault();
  });
 </script>
```

Comment: You could check if the file exists prior to creating the object, and if it already exists either A) rename the file or B) Ajax response with an error message

Comment: @PacketLoss thanks for your response and this is another option but it so hassle to rename the file when it exists why not implement automatically rename the file like through random or increment

Comment: Should work out of box https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/files/storage/#django.core.files.storage.Storage.get_available_name

Answer (score 0):

please try

```
from django.db import models
import os


def get_media_path(model, filename):
    class_name = model.__class__.__name__
    code = str(model.id)
    # here you can change the name
    filename = filename # or another thing
    return os.path.join(class_name, code, filename)


class gallery_photos(models.Model):
    gallery_info_id = models.IntegerField()
    # photos = models.FileField(upload_to='Photos/', unique=True)
    photos = models.FileField(upload_to=get_media_path)
    
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'gallery_photos'
```

and please try to use camelcase for your class names, GalleryPhoto (as only one object) instead of gallery_photos

Comment: Good solution. However, this solution works only if you want to save the file locally. It does not work well with django-storages.